# Invalid redirect URI Linkedin API on iOS App

Tags: ios, oauth-2.0, uri, linkedin-api, redirect

I'm using linkedIn signin for my iOS app. After switching to OAuth2, the call back URI is no longer accepted as i keep getting the error 'invalid redirect URI'. The app URL scheme is called 'Paper' and URL identifier is 'com.Paper'. I understand that i have to set up a URL that begins with 'http://' or 'https://' on linkedin developer page and the address has to match with the callback URI. What would be the Authorized Redirect URLs for the linkedin developer setting?

Answer (score 0):

Use the official LinkedIn sdk for iOS
https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/ios-sdk

Answer (score 0):

In  Authorized Redirect URLs for the linkedin developer setting put the same URL you put in the redirectUrl when you configure the linkedin